# Seg Fault 11 When Trying to Swap Contents of a String

Tags: c, string, char, segmentation-fault, swap

So I'm trying to create a textbuffer which stores lines of a given text into a list. I'm currently writing a swap function, however if I try and adjust certain lines I get a segmentation fault.

This is the current swapfunction I'm using:

```
void swapTB (TB tb, int pos1, int pos2) {

if (tb == NULL) {
    abort();
} 

if (pos1 < 0 || pos1>tb->size || pos2<0 || pos2>tb->size) {
    printf("error: lines are out of range!\n");
    abort();
}

link line1 = findLine(tb, pos1);
link line2 = findLine(tb, pos2);

char *temp = (char *)malloc((strlen(line1->line) + 1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(temp,line1->line);
strcpy(line1->line, line2->line);
strcpy(line2->line,temp);

free(temp);

}
```

if i try and feed this text:

```
char text[] = "0. She walks in beauty, like the night\n"
              "1. Of cloudless climes and starry skies;\n"
              "2. And all that’s best of dark and bright\n"
              "3. Meet in her aspect and her eyes;\n"
              "4. Thus mellowed to that tender light\n"
              "5. Which heaven to gaudy day denies.\n"
              "6. One shade the more, one ray the less,\n"
              "7. Had half impaired the nameless grace\n"
              "8. Which waves in every raven tress,\n"
              "9. Or softly lightens o’er her face;\n"
              "10. Where thoughts serenely sweet express,\n";
```

and do the following swaps:

```
swapTB(tb, 4, 7);
swapTB(tb, 2, 9);
swapTB(tb, 2, 10);
```

it works fine and I get this output:

```
0. She walks in beauty, like the night
1. Of cloudless climes and starry skies;
10. Where thoughts serenely sweet express,
3. Meet in her aspect and her eyes;
7. Had half impaired the nameless grace
5. Which heaven to gaudy day denies.
6. One shade the more, one ray the less,
4. Thus mellowed to that tender light
8. Which waves in every raven tress,
2. And all that’s best of dark and bright
9. Or softly lightens o’er her face;
```

However, if I change the text a little bit, such as shortening line 9:

```
char text[] = "0. She walks in beauty, like the night\n"
              "1. Of cloudless climes and starry skies;\n"
              "2. And all that’s best of dark and bright\n"
              "3. Meet in her aspect and her eyes;\n"
              "4. Thus mellowed to that tender light\n"
              "5. Which heaven to gaudy day denies.\n"
              "6. One shade the more, one ray the less,\n"
              "7. Had half impaired the nameless grace\n"
              "8. Which waves in every raven tress,\n"
              "9. Or softly lightens o’er\n"
              "10. Where thoughts serenely sweet express,\n";
```

I get a Segmentation Fault 11.

This has been happening consistently, sometimes it works fine, sometimes it segmentation faults, and other times it runs but the final output has duplicates -- it all varies depending on the text I'm giving the function.

The text is being stored in a struct like this, by the way:

```
typedef struct textNode *link;

struct textNode {
    char *line;
    link next;
};

struct textbuffer{
    link head;
    link last;
    int size;
};
```

EDIT:

function to allocate newline:

```
link newLine(char text[], int start, int i) {

    link newLine = malloc(sizeof(*newLine));
    assert(newLine != NULL);

    newLine->line = extract(text, start, i);
    //printf("newline is %s\n", newLine->line);
    newLine->next = NULL;

    return newLine;

}
```

the extract function

```
char* extract(const char* src, int start, int end) {

    return strndup(src + start, (end - start)+1);
}
```

function to findLine

```
link findLine(TB tb, int pos) {

    link curr = tb->head;
    int index = 0;

    while (index != pos) {
        curr = curr->next;
        index++;
    }

    return curr;
}
```

Comment: How do you initialize the `line` member? post that code pealse.

Comment: @iharob i fixed it with the pointer solution people posted bellow! but if you're still curious, i used strndup and a while loop that indexed every place after a newline

Comment: Then you have a memory leak now.

Comment: @iharob after the pointer solution, how so?

Comment: because you must `free` the return value of `strdup`. Can you please post `findLine` function?

Comment: @iharob i posted my newline and findline functions in the original post!

Comment: then you are ok, but still you need to `free` all the `link->line` members when you are done using them.

Comment: @iharob yeah, i have a free function for that. thank you~ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write correctly the swap operation. Instead of this code

```
char *temp = (char *)malloc((strlen(line1->line) + 1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(temp,line1->line);
strcpy(line1->line, line2->line);
strcpy(line2->line,temp);
```

there should be

```
char *temp  = line1->line;
lin1->line  = line2->line;
line2->line = temp;
```

As you can see there is no need to copy the strings themselves. It is enough to swap pointers.

Take into account that there is no any sense to define data member `size` as having type `int` that then each time to check whether it is less than zero. It would be much better if size would be defined as having type `size_t`

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that you sometimes write data from a longer string into a space that was previously allocated for a shorter string. The code that does the swap, i.e. these five lines has the problem:

```
char *temp = malloc(strlen(line1->line) + 1); // No need to cast or multiply by sizeof(char)
strcpy(temp,line1->line);
strcpy(line1->line, line2->line);
strcpy(line2->line,temp);
free(temp);
```

Your code makes sure that there is enough space in `temp` for the data from `line1->line`, but make an assumption that there is enough space for the data from `temp` in `line2->line` and also that there is enough space for all characters of `line2->line` in `line1->line`.

To fix this problem either reallocate pointers, or do pointer swap instead of swapping the content, i.e.

```
char *temp = line1->line;
line1->line = line2->line;
line2->line = temp;
```

Comment: This is good advice, specially the `do pointer swap instead of swapping the content` part. That is the way to do this.